# How to save color of background using javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm attempting to allow a web visitor to change the color of a page's background and make sure that when they refresh the page, their background color preference is still displayed on the page.

I've tried using localStorage.setItem() but it doesn't seem to be working. Any suggestions?

**HTML**

```
<button id="changeColorButton" class="btn-secondmenu">Button</button>
<select name="colors" id="changeColorSelect">
   <option value="red">Red</option>
   <option value="green" selected="selected">Green</option>
   <option value="yellow">Yellow</option>
   <option value="black">Black</option>
</select>
```

**JS**

```
$('#changeColorButton').click(function() {
    var color = $('#changeColorSelect').val();
    console.log(color)
    $('body').css("background-color",color);
    localStorage.setItem('background', $(this).val());
});
```

Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: `localStorage.setItem('background', color);`

Comment: I think you've got a context problem here, `this` is not referencing what you think it is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This line

```
localStorage.setItem('background', $(this).val());
```

will save the *value of button element* `$('#changeColorButton')`, *if there is any*

Instead make it

```
localStorage.setItem('background', color);
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code, you are using the click event listener function

```
$('#changeColorButton').click(function() {...}
```

In you click event listener `this` refers to the button and not the changeColorSelect  select. So that is why local storage is not able to store your color.

Instead this would work

```
$('#changeColorButton').click(function() {
    var color = $('#changeColorSelect').val();
    console.log(color)
    $('body').css("background-color",color);
    localStorage.setItem('background', color);
});
```

Hope it helps!